# ngSwitch not working

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive

Year dropdown isnt showing option 3 or 4-
I want to show the Year drop down according to the course selected.

Here is the code-

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="course">Course:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="course" ngModel name="course" #name required>
        <option *ngFor="let course of courses" [value]="course">{{course}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="year">Year:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="year" ngModel name="year" required [ngSwitch]="course">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option *ngSwitchCase="'MCA'">3</option>
        <option *ngSwitchCase="'B. Tech'">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

In component.ts the following array is present-

```
  courses = ['B. Tech', 'M. Tech', 'MBA', 'MCA', 'PGDM'];
```

Comment: I can't see `ngSwitch` inside `ngFor` in your code. `*ngFor` is on the `<option>` element, which only contains `{{course}}`, but no `ngSwitch`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was just about to say the same :)

Comment: I think I used wrong title, I meant I couldn't get ngSwitch working

Comment: Try giving your ngModel a value ? like `[(ngModel)]="course"` ?

Comment: Also try removing quotes from your `*ngSwitchCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngSwitch` is working properly, the only thing you need to change is the binding of the variable to `ngModel` in the first select tag
like : `[(ngModel)]="course"`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="course">Course:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="course" [(ngModel)]="course" name="course" #name required>
    <option *ngFor="let course of courses" [value]="course">{{course}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```